# Cmake doesn't want to download the antlr4 runtime

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to link the antlr library to my project. But, it doesn't want to download the runtime files and compile them. So when I include the antlr-runtime.h file, I get an error. Can you help me figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong?

Project structure:

```
cmake/
    ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake
    FindANTLR.cmake
tools/
    antlr.jar
CmakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(AntlrProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.6.0/msvc2019_64")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        REQUIRED)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(ExternalAntlr4Cpp)

include_directories(${ANTLR4_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(ANTLR_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar)

find_package(ANTLR REQUIRED)

add_executable(AntlrProject main.cpp)
```